# System.debug prints twice

Tags: debug, system

I encountered this weird thing: when I use:

`System.debug();`

I get everything printed twice... and it only happens for the Account object.

I'm guessing this is a reason why my API callout doesn't work but that's another story.

There was few triggers on Account object and I disabled them all except one and still getting this issue.

Does anyone encounter a similar issue?

Comment: Sounds like a workflow rule/field update or process builder. There are a few situations where this might occur naturally, but we would need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on sfdcfox's comment, and your indication that the suggestion was correct, the cause of seeing your debug statements twice is either because of a Process Builder, or a Workflow Rule Field Update.

Both of these are due to the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Specifically... (emphasis mine)

> 11. If there are workflow field updates, **updates the record again**.
> 12. If the record was updated with workflow field updates, **fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time)**, in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again.
> 13. Executes processes and flows launched via processes and flow trigger workflow actions.
>       When a process or flow **executes a DML operation**, the affected record **goes through the save procedure**.

If you have a debug statement in your trigger, and your trigger ends up being run twice, you'll see the debug be printed twice.